# Are there Python code for Scalar Multiplication, Dot Product, Norm (length) without using external library, function?

Tags: python, vector, matrix-multiplication

Here vectors are used as Python tuples. Like the vector `[3;1;1]` is represented in Python as `(3,2,1)`.

1. Write a Python function sca(s,v) that takes 2 arguments: Scalar s and vector v. The function should find result of multiplying the vector by the scalar.

   ```
    sca(3, (1,2,3))     # Returns (3,6,9)
   ```

   Answer may not import any modules or employ any external library functions.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Here are some useful buitins to look into:  [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [sum()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) will come in handy.  As noted, x**.5 is the same as taking the square root.  Of course you could just use loops to accomplish these.  [map()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is nice but since you can't import any modules its use would be limited.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. I am new to Python, so its learning curve for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no builtin functions specifically for this purpose - you will have to write `sca(s, v)` yourself as the question states. The good news is that as long as you are familiar with the mathematical definition of scalar multiplication, this can be implemented in a very short amount of code (4 lines, 1 with some knowledge of Python's more advanced features). Think about how to write that definition in terms of the components of the vector, instead of the entire vector and then think about how to write that in Python.

Answer (score 0):

In short: No

If you do not consider the standard library 'external'. Then math is likely what you have to go with. But it will not support all the needs you specify, out of the box.

Why would you not import any libraries?

Comment: Do you mean `math.sqrt()`? One can do `x ** 0.5` instead.